# How to get ReorderThemeTransition in ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an ObservableCollection where I move the items by

```
oc.Move(oldIndex, newIndex);
```

This ObservableCollection is used as ItemsSource for a ListView. Now I want the ReorderThemeTransition or RepositionThemeTransition, but unfortunately there seems to be a full reset. If I add or delete items, everything is fine (a scaling animation, like it should).

I checked the CollectionChanged Action, but there I get only Moves (as supposed to, no Reset or anything) and I also tried to Move only one element at a time, but still the full list flashes and is reordered.

I tried to add ReorderThemeTransition (and all other transitions) to `ListView.Transitions`, `ListView.ItemContainerTransitions` and to the `ItemsPanel`, which is a ItemsWrapGrid as `ItemsWrapGrid.ChildrenTransition`.

Any ideas, what else I could try?

Comment: What did you mean about "a full reset"? The Move method just move the item to the new location. The remaining items will automatically move up or down.

Comment: I mean, it looks like the whole ListView gets cleared and puts every element in the new order back, without animation.

Comment: Why `ReorderThemeTransition`? Why not `RepositionThemeTransition`?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I tried them all - but I read about ReorderThemeTransition, that's the reason I wrote it here.

Comment: Did you end up with something usefull in the end? I have exactly the same problem: My bound ItemSource gets reordered (by DynamicData), but upon every move all list items look like they are removed and inserted anew. The same behavior occurs if I just do a simple Move on the bound list

Comment: Unfortunately not. Right now I'm not even using UWP anyway since too many restrictions and no usecase anymore (for desktop only I rather use WPF)

Comment: This is why UWP is going to end up on the scrap heap.  There just aren't enough evangelists or success users around to help solve these problems. At least with WPF, I know I can animate something manually instead of being stuck with some backwater initiative that no one supports.

Comment: Seems like this is a known issue and has not been fixed as of today. https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1503